# Interview Postponed, Requested For Earliest Convenience, And Then Back On Schedule?

Tags: interviewing

Recently, I've applied for a job. They got back to me and said that a Skype interview will be in order, on Thursday, 4 days ago. Today they got back to me and said, that due to needing to run errands, they would need to postpone it to next week. I found it funny that all of a sudden errands had to be run when plans were already made. I requested for the Skype interview at that moment, as politely as I could. Then they said that the original appointment could be kept, if that was the case.

I'm feeling very worried, because I applied to another job an they said they would get back to me the night before, regarding my qualifications and experience, only to not get back to me. I think that I may be underqualified for the jobs that I applied. I'm starting to think that these two potential employers may be messing with my head? Please help!

Are the interviewers messing with me due to my inexperience and underqualifications, or am I reading into it too much?

Comment: It sounds as though they're trying to be accommodating.  They had other business crop up so wanted to bump you, and then found the time to interview you when you declared that you'd rather be interviewed sooner rather than later.  What's the actual question here?

Comment: The actual case is a lot more complicated :C

Comment: I actually applied to 3 jobs: the two above, and one more. The two above were exactly what I said about: they went through proper procedure, seen my qualifications and offered interviews. The third one suddenly wanted to see my qualifications AND personal ID, and even pushed me to reply if I wanted to pursue the application. I told the third company to give me more time, and they agreed. I just feel so weird about this.....

Comment: I still don't see what the question is here.  Not all employers interview or request the same information.

Comment: Please clarify your problem: it's not clear what is it! To me it sounds standard HR behavior

Comment: So what´s the question?

Comment: Are the interviewers messing with me due to my inexperience and underqualifications, or am I reading into it too much? :c

Comment: Interviewers aren't messing with you.  They want to fill a role, nothing more than that.

Comment: Thank you! However, may I know if it's odd for a potential employer to ask for qualifications + ID without an interview? The third company suddenly asked for all those and demanded that if I wanted to pursue the application, I should reply right away.....

Comment: Just do whatever each company asks of you.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help! I'll see what I can do!

Comment: Adding more to @JoeStrazzere's comment. Do these two companies make any money by messing with your head?

Comment: Your question has been put on hold as *Unclear what you're asking*. You can [edit] it to improve it, and in that case **be very specific** about Company A,B,C and about your time references - no usage of vague things like *the night before*. Put all facts sequentially, no backtracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DON´T PANIC!

Everything you described sounds quite normal to me. Interview processes can get somewhat chaotic, especially if you apply with smaller companies with no dedicated HR-person.

Searching for new talent is already an expensive and time consuming process. Nobody wants to waste by his time by "messing" with you.

Answer (score 1):

The people interviewing you are just that: people.

Maybe one of them is from HR, but they wanted some technical authority or someone you would be a direct report of to join, but this person suddenly has to travel on-site for a customer on Thursday to solve a pressing problem.
Or their child just got very sick with a high fever and they can't imagine they will be back to work on Thursday. 
Maybe they got sick themselves and would prefer to do the interview later, but definitely not right now, with a headache and sniffling into a growing pile of tissues.

It is not surprising that it would be easier for them to shuffle around whatever came up than making up time instantly on the same day and go into the interview unprepared.

Nobody is messing with you. Life is just generally messing with the plans of anyone.